# having a test debug app and a released debug app side by side

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, versioning, release

When I download my app from the iStore, the latest test version installed to my phone gets over written. Does anyone know how to have two versions of the same app side by side?

On a test project, I edited the build settings so that "realease" and "debug" have different product names. This seemed to solve my problem, however when I try this same trick on my actual project, the two overwrite each other again.

Does anyone have a recommendation? I don't mind how it's done.

Comment: Change the bundle identifier. com.tristan.cool_app for release and com.tristan.cool_app_DEBUG for debuggin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle identifier (in your .plist file) is the differentiator.  Change that, per Jason Coco's comment, and the iPhone upload no longer overwrites -- it's two different apps.

I use this trick to compare AppStore-downloaded app versus AdHoc-distributed app on the same device.

(The quick-and-dirty solution, of course, is to use two devices .... ;-)

Comment: Done thanks! I had trouble with this at first, as I was using the wrong .plist file, not realising that there was another.

I've set the bundle identifier to "com.axle8.${PRODUCT_NAME}". I have different settings for the product name under the release and the debug versions.